# dodge ram 1500 RPM's problems

Tags: dodge, ram

I got a 2007 dodge ram 1500 standard,  when im parked and I accelerate my truck doesnt go over 2500 rpm , reach the 2500 and starts acting like its cutting the gas , but on the freeway I can accelerate ok , I can put it on neutral and accelerate and the rpm can go all the way up , im wonder its that normal or no

Comment: So this odd hesitation only happens when the truck's transmission is in park?  If you're sitting still in neutral there's no problem?

Comment: Well the truck is standard , im not moving the truck is in neutral and if I accelerate doesnt go over 2500 rpm , ani does that only when im completly stopped or im moving no more than 20 m/h

Comment: Have you done any recent tune-ups?

Comment: Nop its been a little bit over a year since I did the last one

Comment: Is it a gasoline engine?

Comment: @HandyHowie - I would think so. I'm pretty sure they didn't put the Cummins in the 1500, but not 100% sure.

Comment: This is normal behavior.  The answer below nails it.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal and is a safety feature. When the car is parked, the ECU will limit the rpm. It is so that the engine is not worn out unnecessarily.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg4J28pbfvE